# How to use CodeSniffer in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: php, netbeans, phpcodesniffer, netbeans-8.1

I have installed Netbeans 8.1 and Xampp for Windows with PHP 5.6.

Netbeans 8.1 has the CodeSniffer installed by default. Xampp too (pear). And Netbeans detects the "standars":

[image: CodeSniffer in Netbeans 8.1]

But now, I don't know how to run CodeSniffer in my php files. There is no button, neither a menu.

How can I run it? In other versions of Netbeans there was an "Eye button" to run it.

Comment: have you googled something? show some effort, its then much easier for us to help

Comment: Yes, but all guides use a custom plugin for netbeans. Since version 8 the plugin is native. An example with netbeans 7: http://subharanjan.com/integrate-php-codesniffer-netbeans-ide-steps/. I don't know where is the "Eye button" in the latest image

Comment: As I see in your image you're in the options, try to go back to the IDE and search again, maybe there's and *action*-Tab or something

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "button" is in the menu Source > Inspect...

http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=64901

Comment: Do you know the shortcut key for Inspect?

Comment: There is none defined by default. You can assign it via Tools -> Options -> Keymap